# How to find out best possible time complexity for an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

After solving a problem by some algorithm, till when do you try to improve it's time complexity? That is, when would you know that your current time complexity is the best possible and there can be no further improvement in asymptotic time complexity. 
I wanted to get this cleared as during an interview, if the interviewer asks me to further optimize an algorithm that cannot be possible optimized, how do I prove mathematically that the algorithm I developed is already the best possible one and that no further "major" optimizations can be done?

Comment: There is no single step by step proof that works for every type of algorithm.

Comment: You can read this for one example: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/problems-that-can-be-used-to-show-polynomial-time-hardness-results

Comment: Note that question talks about reducing problems to 3sum to prove O(n^2).  Interestingly, in 2014 an even lower complexity algorithm for 3sum was found! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

Comment: It's kind of broad, but IMO the idea of reducing problem to some known / obvious problem with it best complexity and argue that "you cannot do better than that" is quite useful most of the time

Answer (score 2):

You're asking how to prove a lower bound on the time complexity of an algorithm.  This is sometimes fairly easy, for example if you're trying to generate an exponential number of things, you can't do better than exponential time or if you need to find the maximum number in an unsorted list, you have to check all of the numbers so the best time bound is linear.  However, this is sometimes insanely difficult.  One of the most important open problems in computer science is the P=NP conjecture which could be solved if someone could prove a lower bound on any of the NP complete problems.  There has been a huge amount of time and effort invested in this approach, but it hasn't yielded any significant results.  Additionally, the lowest possible big-O doesn't necessarily mean there aren't faster algorithms with better constant factors.

In practice, constant factors do matter, so they might just be asking you if you can improve upon the constant factors in your implementation.  Additionally, trying to prove things during interviews is hit or miss at best.  If you're asked to optimize an algorithm further, it's usually because there is a faster way to solve the problem and interviewers will usually ask questions and give hints to try to prompt you towards that sort of solution.

With regards to certain proof techniques, the proof of the nlog(n) bound on comparison sort is an interesting one to look at.  The essential idea of the proof is that there are n! possible permutations of the list and that in the worst case, each comparison can only eliminate half of them.  By Sterling's approximation, this turns into an nlog(n) bound.  That being said, this is a complex topic that is too extensive to discuss directly here.